# How to install Cygwin make package or define the GNUMAKE variable to point in Cocos2d

Tags: android, bash, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am trying apps with cocos2d on running it show the following error.How to solve this. Thank you

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project TestCpp ****

bash D:/WorkSpaceOpengl/TestCpp/build_native.sh 
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: D:\WorkSpaceOpengl\TestCpp
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/WorkSpaceOpengl/TestCpp
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
NDK_ROOT = D:\Android\android-ndk-r8e
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/WorkSpaceOpengl/TestCpp/../../../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/WorkSpaceOpengl/TestCpp/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/WorkSpaceOpengl/TestCpp
Using prebuilt externals
ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.

**** Build Finished ****
```

I searched to install make in cygwin there are so many packages available. Which package is to be install that solve my issue? [Here the link](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=make&arch=x86_64)

Comment: It told you the problem.  Install `make`.

Comment: Thank you for response.Can you suggest me how to install it. am struggling with that.

Comment: Run the cygwin installer and select `make` from the development category.

Comment: Could you provide step by step flow for that? I haven't development category in cygwin installer.

Comment: Try this link for cocos2dx installation.   http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_set_up_the_android_cocos2d-x_development_environment_on_Windows_7

Comment: @user2634966 If you are using eclips you set the build path in the project

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else still struggling with this here's the steps to install make in cygwin :

- Run the cygwin installer from the downloads.
- After choosing the mirror you are shown the packages you can install.
- choose the Devel package (click on it it will turn from "Default" to "Install".
- when the installation is finish run the cmd and command "bash" and check if make installed run "make -v". And you are done.

hope it's helpful.